# Erro na geração de chave artisan

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, artisan

Olá, estou tentando iniciar as correções em um projeto laravel. Depois que fiz o git clone do repositório, tentei gerar php artisan key:generate, e aparece este erro aqui. Alguém sabe me dizer como solucionar este problema?

PHP Warning:  require(/home/*******/*******/*******/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*******/*******/*******/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/*******/*******/*******/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/*******/*******/*******/artisan on line 18

Comment: Ao que parece, pela mensagem de erro, há um arquivo não encontrado...

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema do arquivo não encontrado, mas na hora de gerar o php artisan module:migrate ele dá a seguinte resposta: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ***** and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Answer (score -2):

Você já tem o composer instalado? Verifique isso com `composer -v`

Se não tiver instalado faça isso `composer install`

Se já tiver instalado, tente `composer update`

Há alguns outros comandos para quando ocorrem erros:

`composer dump-autoload`

`composer clear-cache`

Para o problema com a migração das tabelas, você já criou o banco de dados local? O Laravel apenas migra as tabelas e seus dados pra lá, mas ele não consegue criar o banco. Verifique também se o nome do banco que você criou está compatível com o arquivo de configuração .env

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).